# How to find the problem causing slow boot

Tags: boot

I have Ubuntu 18.10 and Fedora installed on my Asus laptop. And I just installed kali Linux (for fun). After the installation, I booted into Ubuntu again and found that the speed of booting became extremely slow. After grub, it hanged at a black screen for about 40 seconds, and then "Ubuntu" with five dots for around 1:30. No error message appeared. I know that it's difficult to help with this information, so I want to ask that how can I get more information about what is causing the problem? (or maybe what may be causing the problem?) I installed Ubuntu and Fedora on my SSD so I expected to be booting very fast. Fedora still boot fast now but not Ubuntu.

As for other information, I share my home partition between Fedora and Ubuntu. I wanted to share with kali but it didn't come up with the same directory after the installation completed. I also tried to share swap partition. During the installation of Kali, I cannot select the current swap partition without formatting it, so I formatted the swap partition. Those are the info I can think of. Please tell me where I can find other needed information to get help. I'm quite new to Linux, so I'll appreciate it if the instruction can be very detailed (such as commands). Thank you in advance.

Comment: keep in mind boot is slower when its doing extra work for say some driver change so subsequent boots will be faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you formatted the existing swap, Ubuntu (and even Fedora) may not be recognizing the swap, which may be a possible cause. Boot to Ubuntu and open the System Monitor to see if the Swap is "not available". Alternatively, type in the terminal `cat /proc/swaps` to see which swap devices are being used.

If the swap is not available, you must to tell the system to use it, because it's UUID changed. These are the steps:

Type in the terminal

```
sudo blkid
```

to see the UUID of the partitions. Search for the swap UUID.
Now, open in the terminal

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

and change the UUID of the swap partition with the new one. The line will be something like this:

```
UUID=e911d747-0add-49dc-a37d-7b6b16656c2g none swap sw 0 0
```

Then restart the system and see if the swap is being detected. Verify if the problem of slow boot was gone.